# SailsJS User upload images

Tags: image, upload, sails.js, assets

I need to let my users upload images. But I don't know where can I create my "uploads" folder and how have access to it in my view.

In SailsJS, we have a folder assets/images, but all images in it will be copied in the public folder .tmp, when we lift sails (with Grunt).
So I can't create my folder in .tmp neither in asset/images.

Someone have a solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Linux-based system, you can just create your `uploads` folder in you project's root and symlink it from `assets` folder:

```
mkdir uploads && cd assets && ln -s ../uploads
```

Once Sails is lifted all the files from the uploads folder will be accessible via `http://your.host.com/uploads/filename.ext`, including the once you upload during runtime.

That said, for large applications in production with a lot of uploads it would make sense to upload files directly to Amazon S3 or something similar and serve them via a CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try ! For Amazon S3 I have made some search. Do you know a CDN service with a free package during the development and a moderate cost for production ?

Comment: @user1853777 Can't really recommend anything specific. MaxCDN worked best for me in terms of price/quality. At the same time, basic Google search comes up with this: http://cloudinary.com/pricing, it says they even have a free package. But I guess you would be better off doing some research on your own. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**To Upload Images**

```
There are two ways to upload images
  1. Upload images to Amazon s3 bucket.
  2. Upload Images mongodb gridFs.


I would like suggest to Uploading images to Aws (Amazon Web Services) S3 bucket why

 S3(Simple Storage Service)

Because S3 bucket is highly Scalable , relaible, fast and inexpensive simple data infrastructure to store.
```

**Example AWS S3 bucket**

```
Amazon provide a library/dependency for javascipt in NodeJs to access S3 bucket.

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var accessKeyId ="JHPSJFPDOKK4YLGMW25kLia";
var secretAccessKey ="kkl96vPMrc9rnDBSs5Yqq2cKMHlham5T2wfjBhj89H";
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.createBucket({Bucket: 'myBucket'}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err){
      console.log(err);  
     }else{
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey")
     }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you skipper module for file upload. In latest versions of Sails, Skipper is the default body parser, so you will be able to use it directly. If you are using Amazon S3, there is skipper-s3 module for uploading to s3. But the best practice woul be to upload the file directly without hitting your server, to any CDN like s3,cloudinary or something else via AJAX request. This will reduce the load on the server.